Terraform multiple for_each in single resource
I'm trying to create multiple Github repos and add files to that newly created repos using a JSON file.
# Terraform Locals
locals {
  binding_pairs = toset([
    for pair in setproduct(
      keys(data.github_repository_file.main),
      keys(github_repository.main),
      ) : {
      files = pair[0]
      repos = pair[1]
    }
  ])
}

locals {
  json_files   = fileset("${path.module}/environments/", "*.json")
  json_data    = [for i in local.json_files : jsondecode(file("${path.module}/environments/${i}"))]
  json_content = { for i in local.json_data : i.github_repo_name => i.github_repo_description }
  terraform_data = [for i in local.json_files : file("${path.module}/environments/${i}")]
}

# Terraform Data Sources
data "github_repository_file" "main" {
  for_each = var.github_repo_files

  repository = var.source_repo_name
  branch     = "main"
  file       = each.key
}

# Terraform GitHub Repository
resource "github_repository" "main" {
  for_each = local.json_content

  name        = each.key
  description = each.value
  auto_init   = true
  visibility  = "public"
}

# Terraform GitHub Repository Files
resource "github_repository_file" "main" {
  for_each = { for p in local.binding_pairs : "${p.files}:${p.repos}" => p }

  repository          = github_repository.main[each.value.repos].id
  branch              = "main"
  file                = data.github_repository_file.main[each.value.files].file
  content             = data.github_repository_file.main[each.value.files].content
  overwrite_on_create = true
}

resource "github_repository_file" "tfvars" {
  for_each = github_repository.main

  repository          = github_repository.main[each.value].id
  branch              = "main"
  file                = "terraform.tfvars"
  content             = local.terraform_data[each.key] **<< This part how to do??**
  overwrite_on_create = true
}

I need to create a terraform.tfvars.json and the content should be from the JSON file. For example, there will be a folder called environments and JSON files will be created inside those folders.
Example: environments/dev-env.json
{
  "github_repo_name": "Dev",
  "github_repo_description": "GitHub Repo for Dev Environment",
  "app_name": "devapp",
  "short_app_name": "devapp",
  "environment": "test",
  "location": "west europe",
  "vnet_address_space": "10.3.0.0/16",
  "subnet_address_space": "10.3.1.0/24",
  "app_subnet_address_space": "10.3.2.0/24"
}

So now I need to create the terraform.tfvars.json files dynamically when someone creates new JSON files in environments folder.
How to create **github_repository_file.tfvars** resource?

Ideally, you would use a map, to create key value pairs between e.g., binding_pairs and terraform_data.

Have you tried jsonencode function?  Try using like this content = jsonencode(local.json_data[each.key]).

@DharaniDharGolladasari as far as I can see, the local json_data variable is a list, so I don't think using keys to access elements would work.

This is a very simple app that you can use to convert json to hcl. To build it, you can have go build . and use it:
main.go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/hashicorp/hcl/hcl/printer"
    "github.com/hashicorp/hcl/json/parser"
)

func main() {
    argsWithProg := os.Args[1]
    input, err := os.ReadFile(argsWithProg)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error: %s", err)
    }
    ast, err := parser.Parse([]byte(input))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error: %s", err)
    }
    err = printer.Fprint(os.Stdout, ast)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error: %s", err)
    }
}

Example:
./app dev.json

This can be a pre-hook before terrafrom plan.
